# How to apply a function column-wise to an Eigen Matrix?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, eigen

I have a `Eigen::MatrixXd(n,m)`. I would like to apply a function `F(one_column)`  to each column of the matrix. How can I do it without using a loop?

My current implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m 1; i++)  // How to Parallel this process?
{       
    Eigen::VectorXd one_column = SigmaPoints.col(i);
    F(one_column);           
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: There is no Eigen functionality to run arbitrary functions on each column of a matrix (there is the `.colwise()` method which allows some functionality). Could you be more specific what `F` is supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you @chtz, my function `F` perform an update to each element in that column. For example, I have column 1 `c1 = (x1, y1, z1)`.  My `F` would update `c1` to become `c1_new = (x1 + a, y1 + b, z1 + c)`.

Comment: That would be `SigmaPoints.colwise() += Eigen::Vector3d(a,b,c);` Actually, in your current implentation you are not modifying `SigmaPoints` at all -- you are working on a copy of it.

Comment: If you just want to add a vector colwise, the vectorized form as stated by @chtz is the best option. Nevertheless, you can use general algorithms to perform it without a plain loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to apply a function F(one_column) to each column of the matrix. How can I do it without using a loop?

You can use c++ algorithms functions + lambdas. For example, if all what you want is just to call a function passing each column as parameter then you can use ... `std::for_each` !

```
const auto myMatrixColwise = myMatrix.colwise();

std::for_each(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), [](const auto &column){
    F(column);
});
```

> my function F perform an update to each element in that column

In that case you should use std::transform instead:

```
auto myMatrixColwise = myMatrix.colwise();

std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column){
    return F(column);
});
```

More concretely:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Core>

Eigen::Vector3d F(const Eigen::Vector3d &column)
{
    Eigen::Vector3d abc;
    abc << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0;
    return column + abc;
}

int main()
{

    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> myMatrix;
    myMatrix << 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0,
            2.0, 20.0, 200.0, 2000.0,
            3.0, 30.0, 300.0, 3000.0;

    std::cout << "Before\n";
    std::cout << myMatrix << "\n";

    auto myMatrixColwise = myMatrix.colwise();

    std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column) {
        return F(column);
    });

    std::cout << "After\n";
    std::cout << myMatrix << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This code should print:

```
Before
   1   10  100 1000
   2   20  200 2000
   3   30  300 3000
After
   2   11  101 1001
   4   22  202 2002
   6   33  303 3003
```

> How to Parallel this process?

The easiest way is using C++17 parallel algorithm alternatives:

```
#include <execution>

auto myMatrixColwise = myMatrix.colwise();

std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column){
    return F(column);
});
```

**Disclaimer**: It is not available for all c++17 "compliant" compilers yet.

> I have column 1 c1 = (x1, y1, z1). My F would update c1 to become c1_new = (x1 + a, y1 + b, z1 + c)

In this last case, as said by @chtz, you can do something plain like:

```
SigmaPoints.colwise() += Eigen::Vector3d(a, b, c);
```